# PostgreSQL "Foreign key constraint failed" error - Seeking a solution

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm developing an application that operates on a PostgreSQL database, and I need assistance with an error I'm encountering. My application uses Prisma to track members' messages and weekly messages. However, when I execute the following code, I receive a "Foreign key constraint failed" error:

```
await prisma.member.upsert({
    where: { unq_member_guild_id_user_id: { guild_id: message.guild.id, user_id: message.author.id } },
    update: {
        top_messages: { increment: 1 },
        top_weekly_messages: { increment: 1 },
        messages: { upsert: { where: { unq_member_message_guild_id_user_id_channel_id: { channel_id: message.channel.id, guild_id: message.guild.id, user_id: message.author.id } }, create: { channel_id: message.channel.id, size: 1 }, update: { size: { increment: 1 } } }, },
        weekly_messages: { upsert: { where: { unq_member_weekly_message_guild_id_user_id_channel_id: { channel_id: message.channel.id, guild_id: message.guild.id, user_id: message.author.id } }, create: { channel_id: message.channel.id, size: 1 }, update: { size: { increment: 1 } } }, }
    },
    create: {
        guild_id: message.guild.id,
        user_id: message.author.id,
        top_messages: 1,
        top_weekly_messages: 1,
        messages: { create: { channel_id: message.channel.id, size: 1 } },
        weekly_messages: { create: { channel_id: message.channel.id, size: 1 } }
    }
});
```

I'm having difficulty understanding why this error is occurring and how to resolve it. My database schema and Prisma model are as follows:

```
generator client {
  provider   = "prisma-client-js"
  engineType = "binary"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Staff {
  guild_id String
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  user_id  String
  member   Member @relation(fields: [guild_id, user_id], references: [guild_id, user_id])

  top_messages       Int @default(0)
  top_chat_messages   Int @default(0)
  top_voices         Int @default(0)
  top_weekly_voices   Int @default(0)
  top_weekly_messages Int @default(0)

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id], name: "unq_staff_guild_id_user_id")
}

model Member {
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  guild_id String

  user_id String

  messages          MemberMessage[]
  voices            MemberVoice[]
  top_messages       Int                   @default(0)
  top_voices         Int                   @default(0)
  top_weekly_messages Int                   @default(0)
  top_weekly_voices   Int                   @default(0)
  weekly_messages    MemberWeeklyMessage[]
  weekly_voices      MemberWeeklyVoice[]
  staff             Staff?

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id], name: "unq_member_guild_id_user_id")
}

model MemberMessage {
  guild_id String
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  user_id  String
  member   Member @relation(fields: [guild_id, user_id], references: [guild_id, user_id])

  channel_id String
  size       Int    @default(0)

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id, channel_id], name: "unq_member_message_guild_id_user_id_channel_id")
}

model MemberVoice {
  guild_id String
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  user_id  String
  member   Member @relation(fields: [guild_id, user_id], references: [guild_id, user_id])

  channel_id String
  size       Int    @default(0)

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id, channel_id], name: "unq_member_voice_guild_id_user_id_channel_id")
}

model MemberWeeklyMessage {
  guild_id String
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  user_id  String
  member   Member @relation(fields: [guild_id, user_id], references: [guild_id, user_id])

  channel_id String
  size       Int    @default(0)

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id, channel_id], name: "unq_member_weekly_message_guild_id_user_id_channel_id")
}

model MemberWeeklyVoice {
  guild_id String
  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  user_id  String
  member   Member @relation(fields: [guild_id, user_id], references: [guild_id, user_id])

  channel_id String
  size       Int    @default(0)

  @@unique([guild_id, user_id, channel_id], name: "unq_member_weekly_voice_guild_id_user_id_channel_id")
}

model Guild {
  id String @unique

  voice_ranks            GuildVoiceRank[]
  staff_tracking         StaffTracking?
  members                Member[]
  staffs                 Staff[]
  member_messages        MemberMessage[]
  member_voices          MemberVoice[]
  member_weekly_messages MemberWeeklyMessage[]
  member_weekly_voices   MemberWeeklyVoice[]
}

model GuildVoiceRank {
  id   Int    @unique @default(autoincrement())
  hour Int    @default(0)
  role String

  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  guild_id String

  @@index([guild_id], name: "unq_guild_voice_rank_guild_id")
}

model StaffTracking {
  enable       Boolean @default(false)
  lowest_role  String  @default("")
  chat_channel String  @default("")
  log_channel  String  @default("")

  guild    Guild  @relation(fields: [guild_id], references: [id])
  guild_id String @unique
}
```

I'm struggling to figure out what might be causing this error. What should I check or fix to resolve this error? Can you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: In which field do you get the foreign key constraint error? If you update your error message more clearly that would help to debug the errors (Because When I look at the table, I found there are a lot of relations between the tables)

Comment: Turn on logging on test system - perform your action, check logs to see what actual SQL wzs sent to the server. Turn off logging of all statements (performance).

Comment: sigh... provide the **complete** error message in your question. Postgres error messages often have very valuable information in them - hiding that detail just makes no sense